# Tool to search for repeated codes in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I am using ArcGIS 10.1.

I have a shapefile that has a field called "Code".

I want to make a Modelbuilder model to check if there are "duplicate" codes.

Is there a tool that could do this?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what do you want to do with them after you've identified duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [Find Identical (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000054000000) tool.

1. Select the field where you would like to find identical records
2. Join the resulting table to the shapefile using the `IN_FID*` field
3. Perform the appropriate corrective actions on the duplicate records
   as marked in the new `FEAT_SEQ` field.

Alternatively, you can use the [Calculate Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) Tool to accomplish this.  There is an [ESRI blog](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38700) on how to identify duplicate records.  Unique values will be marked with "0", while duplicates are marked with "1".  The workflow is as follows:

1. Add new field to shapefile
2. Choose the Python parser
3. Add the following code to the codeblock

---

```
uniqueList = []
def isDuplicate(inValue):
  if inValue in uniqueList:
    return 1
  else:
    uniqueList.append(inValue)
    return 0
```